# Control Evaluation Order in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana, sapb1

I'm having problems porting code from MS-SQL to HANA because HANA doesn't appear to have a reasonable grasp of which pieces of code should be evaluated.

In my scenario, I have a field which has packed data - the data is a single char discriminator which can be 'M', 'E' or 'I' (Machine/Employee/Item) - then a colon, then a value. For 'M:' and 'I:' prefixes, this is a string, for 'E:' prefix this is an integer.

My initial problem is that if I do:

```
CASE LEFT(LB."U_Resource", 1)
```

HANA evaluates code in all of the WHEN clauses of the case whether it needs those values to calculate output or not - worse still, doing so halts the query execution with an error. Is there any way to cause HANA to evaluate this in short-circuit fashion - or otherwise ignore errors until they feed into the output?

My 'E:' clause contains the following code:

```
WHEN 'E'
    THEN 'Emp(' || (
        SELECT "firstName" || ' ' || "lastName"
        FROM OHEM
        WHERE LENGTH(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(LB."U_Resource", 3, 50), '+-.0123456789')) = 0
        AND "empID" = CAST(SUBSTRING(LB."U_Resource", 3, 50) AS INT)
    ) || ')'
```

The error that I get is that the value is not an INT when "U_Resource" is "LABOUR1". This worked on HANA 112.03 where HANA executed left to right and my LH expression protected the RH expression. On HANA 122.05, HANA always executes the RH expression first.

Any help would be appreciated - I think that these are faults in the execution engine.

For context - this is a SAP B1 Database, and the U_Resource" field is a UDF in a user defined table.

Thanks